# Python-Jenkins build job not working

Tags: python, api, jenkins

I want to trigger an build Job in Jenkins through python-jenkins package.
I am able to connect and get jenkins version and last successfull build number but when i request for a build job it gives an authentication error.

```
>>> import jenkins
>>> server = jenkins.Jenkins('http://jenkinshost', 'ahmes', 'mytoken')
>>> server.build_job('job-name', {'param1':'testvalue'},'mytoken')
```

Below is the error :

> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jenkins__init__.py", line 914, in
>   build_job
>       self.build_job_url(name, parameters, token), b''))   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jenkins__init__.py", line 361, in
>   jenkins_open
>       e.code, e.msg) JenkinsException: Error in request. Possibly authentication failed [500]: Server Error

I was able to get the last build number there shouldn't be a authentication error .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Worked on Jenkins 2.7.1 + python 2.7.10 as follows:

```
from jenkinsapi.jenkins import Jenkins
server = Jenkins(jenkinsUrl, userName, userToken)
```

trigger with no parameters or use default parameters values:

```
server.build_job(jobName)
```

trigger with parameters:

```
server.build_job('groovy-post-build',{'PARAM1':'value1', 'PARAM2':'value2'})
```

(PARAM1 and PARAM2 are the names of the parameters in the job)

note: make sure that the user has permission to trigger that job.